# Pseudo 3d with css

Tags: html, css

Here's the situation:

I have a parent view, which has a 3d transformation. On it I have several elements(lets call them objects from now on), which when transformed look like stickers (i.e they don't have an edge). I want these objects to look like they are ON the view (imagine the parent view is a table, and the elements are coins/plates, etc).

My first idea was to insert child elements into these objects and rotate those 90 degrees (see picture), but I can't seem to achieve it (I'm not very good at css). Could anybody help me with this?[image]

Basically, I want something like [this](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/cube-02-show-sides.html), but I need only the 1 and six in my case. I tried to cut out the logic, but [I fall short](http://jsfiddle.net/fm5qw6xh). When I try to add a rotation to the cube, the lements squeeze, instead of behaving like a 3d element:

```
#cube .bottom {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgba(254, 0, 255, 0.7);
}
#cube figure {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 196px;
    height: 196px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    line-height: 196px;
    font-size: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
figure {
    margin: 0px;
}
#cube.panels-backface-invisible figure {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#cube .front {
    transform: translateZ(100px);
}
#cube .front {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
#cube {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 1s ease 0s;
    transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(90deg);    
}
#cube.show-front {
    transform: translateZ(-100px);
}
```

and the html:

```
<div id="cube" class=" panels-backface-invisible show-front">
    <figure class="front">
    1
    </figure>
    <figure class="bottom">
    6
    </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a fiddle of a basic example? Do you want these objects to animate to 90 degrees or just be static at 90 degrees?

Comment: basically, I want something like this -> http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/cube-02-show-sides.html, but I need only the 1 and 6 in my case. I tried to cut out the logic, but I fall short -> http://jsfiddle.net/fm5qw6xh/   when I try to add a rotation to the cube, the lements squeeze, instead of behaving like a 3d element

Comment: Like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/fm5qw6xh/1/ the example uses modernizer script but using the transform property is key for this

Comment: @jbyrne2007 , ok I'll look through it. Thanks